# Update field with null in postgresql with limit

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

So I need a query that would null the content in specific field. That's quite easy, but I need it with a limit that I would specify. For selecting the field with `LIMIT` and `FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED` I know the query. I need something similar but with `UPDATE`. Here what I've come with:

`UPDATE e_message SET message = null FROM (SELECT * FROM e_message where created < :created ORDER BY :created LIMIT :limit FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED)`

I specify the created and limit variables in java.

Would this work or did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there:

```
UPDATE e_message AS e
SET message = null
FROM (SELECT id FROM e_message
      where created < :created
      ORDER BY :created
      LIMIT :limit
      FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED) AS e2
WHERE e.id = e2.id;
```